# How can I improve my control over spray paint?

Tags: paint

I wanted to start with some spray painting art. I am talking about a technique used to paint planets in space. Something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNoEQrgyAZk).

I ordered Montana Black spray paint cans (I have a feeling that this was a bad choice and I should have bought the Gold line instead) and all caps from the Montana portfolio.

But I have a problem with the amount of paint. It doesn't matter which cap I use, everytime it gives too much paint on too large an area. Is this because of the high-pressure cans? I tried to paint from a larger distance, but it covers a larger area, so...

If you have any more tips, please tell me, as I am a total beginner.

Answer (score 3):

Spray painting needs some getting used to. With these cans, you have to work quickly, and use smooth hand gestures. Mind as well, that they are used to paint large areas by default.

For your purpose, I suggest you buy cans from the Montana Gold line.

> Montana GOLD is the perfect tool for all artists and creative workers.
>   The **specially developed low-pressure system guarantees maximum
>   accuracy** to meet the highest requirements while giving professional
>   results! High-covering and quick-drying acrylic lacquer.
>
> <sup>[source](https://www.montana-cans.com/en/spray-cans/montana-spray-paint/gold-400ml-artist-paint/montana-gold-400ml-colors)</sup>

The change in coverage between different types of nozzles can be significant, too. That all of them don't work well for you, probably is a sign that you bought a wrong set - these cans are perfectly fine for (relatively) detailed work. Naturally, a stable and sure hand will also have a huge impact.

I'd suggest you **look into the different cap levels** by Montana, as demonstrated in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVBQiIJOv7g). Here is a chart showing the same differences in their levels system:

[image: Montana nozzles level comparison sheet]

Of course, other manufacturers will have different and specialized nozzles, as well. I suggest you compare whatever brand you can get your hands on, and see for yourself which work the best for you.

As for some tips:

- After use, turn the can upside down, and spray (unto something that is allowed to go to waste) until only the gas comes out. This will clean both the nozzle, and the tube of the can.
- Additionally, clean the nozzles directly after use. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIhY4zfLPZM) is a good way to do so.
- I have only rarely used spray paint for detailed work in the past, so as to working techniques, I cannot really give any - except the general rule that practice makes perfect: keep experimenting and your technique (and fun) will improve.

Comment: **Thank you very much**. During waiting for some response I was looking for hints what I am doing wrong on youtube and found the same you mentioned, I am too slow and do not proper moves. I have to try do same lines as the shown ones in the video you recommeded me as comparation and practice. Only difference is that I have high-pressure cans (Black)...

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten to address that issue. Answer updated. I always assumed the Black line was their general purpose one, since those were the first cans I ever used as well.

Comment: Would it help to do several light coats?